# How do I set up Nginx to work with Laravel on windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows, nginx

am deploying a Laravel 8.x app using Nginx but its like am missing something because all am getting is a 403. Can someone please point me in the right direction.
Here is a segment of my nginx.config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   C:/xampp/htdocs/my_laravel_app/public;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           C:/xampp/htdocs/my_laravel_app/public;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

}

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: I have gone though the documentation but i cant quite follow. Please give more direction